# Steam is an "essential system package"?

Tags: software-installation, steam, mate

Today I installed Ubuntu MATE. I went to the software boutique section from the welcome screen to start installing software, I install Steam however it doesn't work no matter how many times I click it. I thought I could just uninstall it, but whenever I try to, a dialog box pops up stating that Steam is an essential system package. How do I fix this problem? I am running Ubuntu MATE 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install it through the software centre or through the installer from Steam's website? Try
sudo apt-get purge steam
then install it from the steam website.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue of removing the previous Steam package, try this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge steam*
```

If you want help properly installing Steam, I can definitely assist you! =)

[Download this file](http://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb) to `~/Downloads`

- Open Terminal and enter:

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  sudo apt-get install python-apt
  sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
  ```
- Open the newly added "Steam" launcher & accept the EULA.

If you haven't yet, you might need to install the proprietary graphics drivers for your system.